# Twice Open Color Dialog box?

Tags: vb.net, mouseclick-event, colordialog

I have a form with 8 command button, I use `AddHandler` for Click event for all buttons.

but when I press a button, `cmbColor_Click` run twice.

```
Public Sub OpenForm()
    AddHandler cmbColor1.Click, AddressOf cmbColor_Click
    AddHandler cmbColor2.Click, AddressOf cmbColor_Click
    AddHandler cmbColor3.Click, AddressOf cmbColor_Click
    AddHandler cmbColor4.Click, AddressOf cmbColor_Click
    AddHandler cmbColor5.Click, AddressOf cmbColor_Click
    AddHandler cmbColor6.Click, AddressOf cmbColor_Click
    AddHandler cmbColor7.Click, AddressOf cmbColor_Click
    AddHandler cmbColor8.Click, AddressOf cmbColor_Click
End Sub


Private Sub cmbColor_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim _color As New ColorDialog
    Dim _button As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    _color.Color = _button.BackColor
    If _color.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        _button.BackColor = _color.Color
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: possibly, you called `AddHandler` twice for the same button? try to put a break point on the `AddHandler` calls. Also, you can examine (with debugger or with some trace) the `sender` parameter of your event handler: is it always the same or does it change between the two calls?

Comment: You might have registered the method in the designer as well and then copied it to all the other buttons

Comment: If those are `Buttons`, why are they prefixed with "cmb", which generally indicates a `ComboBox`? The only thing worse than Hungarian Notation is misleading Hungarian Notation.

Comment: @jmcilhinney cmbSomething => commandButtonSomething. As misleading as it can be :O

Comment: You can use `RemoveHandler cmbColor1.Click, AddressOf cmbColor_Click` etc. before the AddHandler. It is not an error if the handler is not associated to the event. (You should put those cmbColor references in an array and loop through them to remove/add the handler.)

Comment: Erno's guess sounds good, but is not accurate.  The designer uses the Handles keyword.  These AddHandler calls do not belong in an OpenForm() method, calling this method more than once causes the problem.  They belong in the constructor, add Sub New if necessary.  Or use the debugger, set a breakpoint on the method to find out where the second call is coming from.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Morton.

Answer (score 0):

If the event handler is being called twice for one event then the event handler has been attached to the event twice.

Ideally, you would track down why AddHandler is being used more than once and eliminate the problem.

However, as a quick fix, you can remove the event handler before adding it - it is not an error to try to remove a non-existent event handler.

So...

```
Friend Sub OpenForm()
    Dim cmbs = {cmbColor1, cmbColor2, cmbColor3, cmbColor4, cmbColor5, cmbColor6, cmbColor7, cmbColor8}
    For Each cmb In cmbs
        RemoveHandler cmb.click, AddressOf cmbColor_Click
        AddHandler cmb.click, AddressOf cmbColor_Click
    Next
End Sub
```